# "Jump" operators from Lindblad equation where the external system is measurements

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-computer, quantum-measurements, open-quantum-systems

How do we derive the "jump operators" for the Lindblad equation if the external system is measurements? [For example in this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.09138)  for the Bose Hubbard system  the Lindblad operators turned out to be the following :

[image: operL]

With such a Hamiltonian:

[image: H]

What exactly changes the fact that we consider external interactions as measurements (the results of measurements 1 and 0)?How do such operators still output in this example?